# How to test a function within a function in R?

Tags: r, unit-testing, closures, testthat

I would like to use the `testthat` package to test a function that is enclosed by another function.

How can I test such a function?

If this is not possible, how can I refactor the code so that testing `objective_function` is possible?

---

Illustrative Example

```r
model <- function(parameter) {
  objective_function <- function(x) {
    (x - p)^2
  }

  # Make parameter integer
  p <- round(parameter)
  result <- optimize(objective_function, c(-10, 10))
  result$minimum
}

# Works
testthat::expect_equal(model(4.2), 4)

# Does not work
# And how would you pass p to the following?
testthat::expect_equal(objective_function(4.2), 4)
#> Error in objective_function(4.2): could not find function "objective_function"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Why not add the `objective_function()` to your package (`R/` folder) and write separate unit tests for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach: explicitly set function scope within model function:

```
objective_function <- function(x) {
  (x - p)^2
}

model <- function(parameter) {
  # Make parameter integer
  p <- round(parameter)
  environment(objective_function) <- environment()
  result <- optimize(objective_function, interval=c(-10, 10))
  result$minimum
}

model(4.2)

p <- 4
objective_function(4.2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my use case I have multiple functions like `objective_function` each depending on multiple parameters from the one environment of the enclosing function. How can I apply your strategy of passing those parameters down from the `model` environment, without explicitly writing them out (which would make the code very messy)?

Comment: One approach is to evaluate the objective functions using the `with` command, to set it's evaluation environment.

Comment: Would you mind modifying your answer, keeping the `p` implicit and using the `with` idea? I'd then be happy to accept it.

Comment: Using `with` didn't work like I thought, since function environment is defined at the time of definition.  However, you can explicitly set the function environment.  See if the revised answer makes sense.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Since I have multiple functions, do you have any idea how I could apply this idea to all of them without repeating myself? For some reason `mapply(\`environment<-\`, function_list, environment())` does not work.

Comment: How about using `get` on each function name?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Rstudio, trying both `debugonce(model)` and `debugonce(objective_function)` could be your answer.